# Integrating Bootstrap-datepicker with MVC4 Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to integrate a date picker into my form over the existing code.
What I have at the moment is:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.dateOfBirth)
```

and I would like the existing date picker to be replaced with the Bootstrap one.

I have already installed the files via the NuGet Package console. In the < head> section I have pasted:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker()
            $('#sandbox-container .input-append.date').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
            });
        });
</script>
```

and in the < body> I have:

```
<div class="input-append date">
    <input type="text" class="span2"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

This is pretty much what the documentation specified but obviously I am going wrong somewhere. Could somebody please assist me with this issue.

Comment: Even when I tried to replace the $('.datepicker').datepicker() with $('.dateOfBirth').datepicker(). It did not replace the existing picker with the new one?¿?¿

Comment: Doesn't it render the `dateOfBirth` as an id instead of a class? Then you might need to change it to: `$('#datepicker').datepicker();`. And don't forget the semi-colon at the end.

Comment: Thanks bump. Still not working. I think it may be the way I am calling it in the view. i.e. the aspx code. Any way you can help there? :)

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? (I.e.: FireBug Console (firefox) or Chrome.)

Comment: No errors. It just displays and empty textbox. When I click it, there is no response